# Javascript - Remove duplicate ID from array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, duplicates

Take the following two arrays:

```
const array1 = [
  {
    props: {
      type : 'text',
      id : 'item1',
      name : 'item1',
      value : '@item1@',
    },
  },
  {
    props: {
      type: 'hidden',
      id: 'item2',
      name: 'item2',
      value: '@item2@',
    },
  }
];

const array2 = [
  {
    props: {
      type: 'hidden',
      id: 'item1',
      name: 'item1',
      value: '@item1@',
    },
  }
];
```

What I'm trying to do is concatenate them into a single array, and remove any duplicates based on the `id` property. However the caveat here is that the object that does **NOT** have a `type` of `hidden` must have presidence.

So I should basically be left with the contents of `array1`, as the duplicate item from `array2` has the `type` value of `hidden`, like so:

```
// Result
[
  {
    props: {
      type : 'text', // Note the type here is "text"
      id : 'item1',
      name : 'item1',
      value : '@item1@',
    },
  },
  {
    props: {
      type: 'hidden',
      id: 'item2',
      name: 'item2',
      value: '@item2@',
    },
  }
];
```

---

I can easily concatenate them using:

```
const array = array1.concat(array2);
```

My idea was to then use a [Filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) but I'm having a bit of a brain melt. Here is what I have come up with so far:

```
const concat = (array1, array2) => {
  const array = array1.concat(array2);
  const ids = [];

  // Create array of ID's
  for (const i in array1) {
    ids.push(array1[i].props.id);
  }

  return array.filter((obj) => {
    if (obj.props.type !== 'hidden' && ids.includes(obj.props.id)) {
      return true;
    }

    return false;
  });
};
```

Would using a [Reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) be a better approach here?

Here is a JSFiddle of what I have so far: https://jsfiddle.net/64uprbhn/

Comment: Do you want to *discard* all `type: "hidden"` or always keep them? I'm a bit confused because I don't think you mistyped "must have presidence", sounds like you meant to say "must have precedence". But I want to double check.

Comment: @VLAZ Let's say 2 objects contain the same ID (`item1`)....one of the object's had `type:hidden` and the other is `type:xxx`. The one that has `type:hidden` should be the one to be removed as the duplicate

Comment: OK, gotcha. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the wanted result?

Comment: @Melchia updated as requested

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can

1. Create a Map of `id => object` from the first array
2. Go over the second array and either

   - add the item if not already in the map
   - check if the current item is not `type: "hidden"` and overwrite the other one
   - otherwise discard the item
3. Create a new array from the Map

```js
const array1 = [
  {
    props: {
      type : 'text',
      id : 'item1',
      name : 'item1',
      value : '@item1@',
    },
  },
  {
    props: {
      type: 'hidden',
      id: 'item2',
      name: 'item2',
      value: '@item2@',
    },
  },
  {
    props: {
      type: 'hidden',
      id: 'item3',
      name: 'item3',
      value: '@item3@',
    },
  }
];

const array2 = [
  {
    props: {
      type: 'hidden',
      id: 'item1',
      name: 'item1',
      value: '@item1@',
    },
  },
  {
    props: {
      type: 'text',
      id: 'item3',
      name: 'item3',
      value: '@item3@',
    },
  }
];

//1. create a map from id => object pairs
const map = new Map(array1.map(obj => [obj.props.id, obj]));

//2. go over the second array
array2.forEach(obj => {
  if (!map.has(obj.props.id) //not a duplicate
    || obj.props.type !== "hidden") { //is not hidden
    //insert
    map.set(obj.props.id, obj);
  }
});

//3. convert back into array
const merged = [...map.values()];

console.log(merged);
```

For the record, you can basically do the same (or pretty similar) thing using `.filter` but you'll have to do a `O(n)` lookup for each item. A Map ensures much faster lookups.

Comment: Legend! Thank you so much. I didn't even think of using a Map

Answer (score 0):

```js
const array1 = [
  {
    props: {
      type : 'text',
      id : 'item1',
      name : 'item1',
      value : '@item1@',
    },
  },
  {
    props: {
      type: 'hidden',
      id: 'item2',
      name: 'item2',
      value: '@item2@',
    },
  }
];

const array2 = [
  {
    props: {
      type: 'hidden',
      id: 'item1',
      name: 'item1',
      value: '@item1@',
    },
  }
];

function getUnique(arr, comp) {

  const unique = arr
    .map(e => e[comp])

    // store the keys of the unique objects
    .map((e, i, final) => final.indexOf(e) === i && i)

    // eliminate the dead keys & store unique objects
    .filter(e => arr[e]).map(e => arr[e]);

  return unique;
}

const arr = array1.concat(array2);

console.log(getUnique(arr, 'id'));
```

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't preserve items that do not have a duplicate

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me

```js
const someItems = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 1 }]

function getUniqueItems(items) {
  const uniqueIds = new Set(items.map((item) => item.id))

  const itemsWithUniqueIds = [...uniqueIds].map(id => items.find(item => item.id === id)).filter(Boolean)

  return itemsWithUniqueIds
}

console.log(getUniqueItems(someItems))
```

If you are using TypeScript, TS will complain about the `.filter(Boolean)`. In that case just replace `Boolean` with `(item: any | undefined): item is any => Boolean(item)`. Of course, you can then go ahead and also replace `any` with whichever type makes sense in your case.